# How to fetch record from Postgres jsonb column with case insensitive manner?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am writing a sql query to fetch data from a jsonb column with case insensitive manner.
but i am facing some issue.

**DB data:**

```
select * from enterprise.contacts;

id  data
--------------------------------
1   {"email": "abc@gmail.com", "interest": ["Cricket", "football"]}
2   {"email": "mno@gmail.com", "interest": ["Cricket"]}
3   {"email": "xyz@gmail.com", "interest": ["cricket", "Football"]}
```

> I am trying to fetch data who has interest is cricket. (With case
> ignore)
>
> Below query I tried, and I am getting only one record, but it should
> give 3 records total as cricket is present in 3 rows.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT * from enterprise.contacts where ( (data->'interest' @> '"cricket"'));

Output:
id  data
--------------------------------
3   {"email": "xyz@gmail.com", "interest": ["cricket", "Football"]}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id  data
--------------------------------
1   {"email": "abc@gmail.com", "interest": ["Cricket", "football"]}
2   {"email": "mno@gmail.com", "interest": ["Cricket"]}
3   {"email": "xyz@gmail.com", "interest": ["cricket", "Football"]}
```

What should be the correct query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a jsonb with `citext` capabilities.

You could create a GIN index on the expression `lower((data->'interest')::text)::jsonb` and use that exact expression in your searches:

```
where lower((data->'interest')::text)::jsonb   @>   '"cricket"'
```

Another approach would be to lower-case the whole jsonb before inserting the field, but that might have unwanted consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You not get all rows because case sensitive comparison. You need to use lower function for compare all strings in lower case like:

```
select * 
from contacts 
where (lower(data::text)::jsonb->'interest' @> '"cricket"');
```

The result:

```
+====+=================================================================+
| id | data                                                            |
+====+=================================================================+
| 1  | {"email": "abc@gmail.com", "interest": ["Cricket", "football"]} |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | {"email": "mno@gmail.com", "interest": ["Cricket"]}             |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | {"email": "xyz@gmail.com", "interest": ["cricket", "Football"]} |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c7123b24141e18824a7d5219c17399e7&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EXISTS condition together with unnesting the elements:

```
select c.*
from contacts c
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements_text(c.data -> 'interest') as i(interest)
              where lower(i.interest) = 'cricket')
```